# How to stream internal audio+screen of android using mediaRecorder?

Tags: android, audio-recording, live-streaming, android-mediarecorder, libstreaming

I am currently able to record and save android screen and audio using mediaRecorder.
I want to stream android screen to vlc and web browser. I have tried the libstreaming library but due to the glitches and no audio I am looking for another way to stream android screen?

is there any other way to stream live android screen with audio which I can stream live android screen to vlc and web browser.

Comment: What do you mean by vlc and web browser ?

Comment: Basically, I want to mirror my android screen to pc using rtsp or http turning my mobile to a server (local server). So, i can open the url in VLC media player or in browser.
I have a sample app [here](https://github.com/sszhangpengfei/AndroidShow). it sharing video perfectly but not sharing audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all, we need to break the project into pieces**

1- Create a screen recorder first of all.
2- save it as a temporary file and break into packets and send it to the network.
3- or don't create files and directly send the packets to the network.
4- for this purpose you can use the library of libstreaming open source available on github. It is mainly available for the camera streaming but you have to feed the data of screen recording and this library will convert the data to packets and send it to the network.

5- you can access the stream by using real time streaming protocol.